# C++: const for class members

Tags: c++, constructor, member

I have a class with various members that I only assign at the constructor phase:

```
class Pet {
    const int id;
    std::string name;

    Pet(int iid, std::string nname) {
        id = iid;
        if (nname != "") { name = nname; }
        else { name = "Johnny Doey"; }
    }

    Pet() : Pet{ -1, "" } {}
}
```

I'm fairly new at C++, but wouldn't it make sense to make these members `const`? However, simply adding the `const` keyword doesn't work ("expression must be a modifiable lvalue"), so how would I do it?

Comment: Yes, you should make those members `const` if they are not meant to be modified after the object is constructed. You can do that initialization in a member-initializer-list.

Comment: Note that some care must be taken with assigning to `name`. You can use the [ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) in the member-initializer list to make sure you perform the correct assignment at initialization.

Comment: const members are problematic because they prevent copy assignment and construction. consider making them private and adding accessors.

Comment: It's too bad this is closed. I actually did read the link that is given as duplicate, but I don't know how exactly I would use this in this example (e.g. with two or more member variables). :(
@Thomas: Hmm, in another thread I saw that setters and getters are bad and a sign of bad programming. :/

Comment: @Markstar imho using them to make an object immutable is a perfectly good use case. [Idiomatic Way to declare C++ Immutable Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858518/idiomatic-way-to-declare-c-immutable-classes)

Comment: see [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) for initializing multiple members. Setting them inside the constructor is too late, the objects are already const.

Comment: [maybe this helps](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b49299c2171a2e1f)

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you VERY MUCH!!! for your replies! Regarding the initializer list: Thank you, I will see how far I can stretch this concept. I did plan on doing some calculations before assigning some values (e.g. integrating the id and some other info into the name if one isn't given). An alternative may be a factory method of some sort.

Comment: Regarding the code, could you please tell me why in line 12 there is a `const` at the end of the line? Thanks again! (also, I notice, that the variables themselves are not `const`)

Comment: it is considered good practice to mark members that don't modify an object const. that is also a prerequisite to calling the method on a const object. see [Const Correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)